# Can i pass values using <a href with spaces in it

Tags: php

Im trying to pass two values to a second page
One of the values is a name (eg John Doe) and have spaces
when i $_Request in on the other page and echo it only John shows

Heres from the 1st page

```
<td> "."<a rel=facebox href=add.php?id=".$id."&acname=".$row['name'].">".$row['name']."</a>". "
```

Second Page

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$acname=$_REQUEST['acname'];
```

Trying to echo it here

```
<td><input type="text"  name="c_id" id="c_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" 
<td><input type="text"  name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo $acname; ?>"
```

Can this be done?
OR should i try a different approach

Comment: you'll need to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) `$row['name']`: `....&acname=".urlencode($row['name']).">...`. Then a space will be encoded as `%20` and passed properly.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) your user input should be escaped before being printed out to the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) `$row['name']`:

```
//                                                           here:
echo "<td> "."<a rel=facebox href=add.php?id=".$id."&acname=".urlencode($row['name']).">".$row['name']."</a>";
```

Then a space will be encoded as `%20` and passed properly.

Comment: Thank you Jeff .. it now echo all of it .. Appreciate your help . and quite fast to be answered ...

Answer (score 0):

Someone beat me to it by a few seconds in a comment, but I'll answer anyway since I had a link as well:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

`urlencode` changes spaces either to `+` or `%20`, and maps other characters as well to make sure they are suitable for use in a URL.

Comment: ..and I didn't have a link in my comment?

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the value to the second page, you have to urlencode it:

```
<td> "."<a rel=facebox href=add.php?id=".$id."&acname=".urlencode($row['name']).">".$row['name']."</a>". "
```

Comment: Solved Thank You